# How does Scalatra send params to the routes?

Tags: scala, scalatra

I'm asking this as a relatively new person to Scala. I've seen examples of how to create 'control constructs' in Scala, but I don't know it well enough to follow the code of Scalatra itself.

Can someone please explain how 'params' is passed to the defined route handlers? I feel like that's a useful technique and I'd like to know how it's done.

Thank you!

Edit: Adding in the sample code from the Scalatra website to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
class HelloWorldApp extends ScalatraFilter {
  get("/") {
    <h1>Hello, {params("name")}</h1>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the traits involved:

```
trait ScalatraFilter extends Filter with ServletBase
trait ServletBase extends ScalatraBase with SessionSupport with Initializable
trait ScalatraBase extends ScalatraContext with CoreDsl with DynamicScope.....
```

when using params you are using one of the few overloaded methods defined in ScalatraBase

```
def params(key: String)(implicit request: HttpServletRequest): String = params(request)(key)
def params(key: Symbol)(implicit request: HttpServletRequest): String = params(request)(key)
def params(implicit request: HttpServletRequest): Params = new ScalatraParams(multiParams)
```

check the code

https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/develop/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/ScalatraBase.scala
https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/develop/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/ScalatraFilter.scala
https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/develop/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/servlet/ServletBase.scala

Comment: Aha, I thought it was a variable being passed in. Making it a method makes sense. Thanks for the information and the links!

Answer (score 0):

It's done by using Scala's `DynamicVariable` class. Here's a short blog post that explains it really well.

http://www.riffraff.info/2009/4/11/step-a-scala-web-picoframework